# Where can I find 'mtrace' Perl script for reading the outpout of MALLOC_TRACE environment variable?

Tags: mtrace

As I have asked in th title, I have the 
output of the mtrace() facitility, but
I cannot find the related mtrace perl script.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It comes with the source code for glibc.  You can find that from various places

Answer (score 0):

In the debian package libc-devtools